# Why are the images produced by pdfimages different when using the -all flag?

Tags: command-line, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

It's my understanding that `pdfimages -all` extracts images from PDFs in their native formats.

Therefore, I expected that the JPG (lossy) images extracted from that command would have the same pixel information as the .ppm and .pbm files produced without the `-all` option, as well as the  PNG (lossless) files created when I right-click and save the image in Evince.

However, my use of the ImageMagick `compare` command tells me that there are differences in the images contained within the JPG files compared to the other options above.
To reproduce, download the PDF in this link (https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2149405), use it as an argument for `pdfimages` and `pdfimages -all` and use the first .ppm file and the first .jpg file as arguments for `compare`.  When I do this, it produces an image file containing red to indicate a difference in the images.

Is there something that I don't understand?  Is `pdfimages` adding pixel information by default when it creates .ppm and .pbm files?

Comment: Just how much difference is there between these images?  Can you supply examples?

Comment: @John1024 I'm trying to get images displaying the problem, but the PNG's seem to be too large for Stack Overflow/Imgur.

Comment: @John1024 Would a link to a PDF source be of any help?  To reproduce, download it, use it as an argument for `pdfimages` and `pdfimages -all` and use the first .ppm file and the first .jpg file as arguments for `compare`.  When I do this, it produces an image file containing red to indicate a difference in the images - https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2149405

Comment: I tried that and saw some red.  I also tried using `convert` to convert a jpg to ppm (no pdf involvement) and then running `compare` on the two; I still got differences.  It might be that there are some rounding-error issues with the conversion process that `convert` detects.

Comment: @John1024 Are you suggesting that these rounding-error issues may also apply to `pdfimages -all`?

Prior to using a newer version of `pdfimages` for the `-all` flag, I was able to use `convert` on the example to convert it from .ppm to .png without getting red, but I also got red when I tried converting to .jpg with it.

Comment: I was expecting that rounding errors occurred upon conversion to or from a lossy format (jpg).   [As another possibility, which doesn't apply here, I would expect rounding errors to occur with conversion between true-color (24bit) and reduced-color (8bit).]   So, I would expect `pdfimages -all` would give you the 'correct' image and conversion of a jpg (whether from a pdf or otherwise) to ppm would add (small) rounding errors.  Having been frustrated with the imprecision of compare's  documentation, I was hoping to do my own direct comparison but I haven't had enough free time yet.

Comment: @John1024 So you're saying that you think that `pdfimages -all` is producing the true image as it is stored on the .pdf while `pdfimages` (without `-all`) is altering the image to convert to .ppm, but am unsure?

Comment: I just did a test (see answer) and `pdfimages -all` produces the exact byte-for-byte true image file.  So, differences between the ppm and the jpg would appear to be errors produced when the conversion to ppm occurred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pdfimages -all` returns the *exact* file that was stored in the pdf.

We can test this by doing a round-trip: starting with a jpg image, we add it to a pdf using LaTeX, extract it using `pdfimages -all`, and then compare it to the original.  (The reason for using LaTeX will be explained later.)

I have the first jpg image as extracted from your link and I named it `device.jpg`.  Let's put it in a PDF file using LaTeX:

```
$ cat img.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5in,keepaspectratio]{device}
\end{document}
$ pdflatex img
[...snip...]
Output written on img.pdf (1 page, 672455 bytes).
Transcript written on img.log.
```

Now, let's extract it using `pdfimages -all` and compare it with the original:

```
$ pdfimages -all img.pdf img-all
$ cmp device.jpg img-all-000.jpg 
$
```

The extracted jpg is *byte-for-byte identical* to the original.

#### Footnote: the reason for using LaTeX

The above test cannot be done using just any PDF creator.  This is because not all PDF creators will put images into a PDF unmolested.  For example, let's try ImageMagick's `convert`:

```
$ convert device.jpg device.pdf
$ pdfimages -all device.pdf device-all
$ cmp device.jpg device-all-000.jpg 
device.jpg device-all-000.jpg differ: byte 4, line 1
```

`convert` re-sampled the image to a smaller size before placing it in the pdf.

```
$ ls -1s device.jpg device-all-000.jpg 
528 device-all-000.jpg
656 device.jpg
```

Image accuracy was part of pdflatex's design goals.  Other PDF creation software may, by default, "optimize" images before placing them in the PDF.

**Update:** [ShreevatsaR](https://askubuntu.com/users/6487/shreevatsar) points out that the [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) utility also provides a lossless method to convert images to PDF.  Non-TeX users will also likely find it much simpler to use.

Comment: To insert an image losslessly into a PDF, apart from LaTeX, one can also use `img2pdf` ([GitLab](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf), [GitHub](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf)).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Interesting.  Thanks!  Answer updated with a link to `img2pdf`.